# Xcode minimum version to launch app to appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, app-store, xcode7.3

I have developed a app using Xcode7.3.1 with swift 2.2.

Is it possible to launch my app to Appstore else i want to upgrade my Xcode and swift syntax to latest version?

Comment: in my knowledge you need to update, reason swift syntax is changed in 3.1

Comment: why it is deprecated??

Comment: and i heard swift 2.2 , 2.3 and 3 not supported in swift 3.1

Comment: is it possible to launch now??so that i can update later

Comment: ya you can launch ,but  ensure once your app support ivp6 and support latest swift sytanx

Comment: see this once for apple release notes https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itunes connect says

> Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0
>   or later.

[image]

So it is safe to say that you can definitely go with Xcode 7.x and Swift 2.2

Comment: what is meant by application loader sorry no idea about that can you say that??

Comment: @sathishkumar  - application loader is the alternate way to upload your app to appstore , your get details in xcode preference , more reference https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html

Comment: Thanks @Bhumit Mehta i will accept this as my answer

Comment: Application loader is a alternative tool of XCode to upload app's to App Store using .ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your app developed on Xcode 7.x without upgrading xcode. Its not compulsory to use Swift 3.0 - You can submit app even if its developed with 2.x. At the end your ipa will have binary code after compilation.

But keep in mind few things:

- There are few APIs which are deprecated. You will have to remove these in future version anyhow.
- Your app must be compatible with 64 bit.

So Its not compulsory, but advisable to upgrade to latest xcode. But if you are in hurry, you can push current version on appstore and take time to make app working with latest Xcode.

Comment: api's or ipa ??

Comment: APIs -  Check "Deprecated APIs" - last section here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html

Comment: Change the Architectures build setting in your project to “Standard Architectures (including 64-bit).” Compile and run. If it run successfully -- You are ready to go.